# php mysql select duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

this is my table

```
id    name    score   date
1     John    5       2012-01-14
2     smith   7       2012-01-12
3     mariah  9       2012-03-22
4     John    8       2012-05-23
```

Well, I want to select the score of each person, but with `limit 1` It means that
if there are two or more scores for John, I want to select the one witch is more recent.
like this

Output:

```
id    name    score   date
2     smith   7       2012-01-12
3     mariah  9       2012-03-22
4     John    8       2012-05-23
```

Should I use Group by ?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  mt.*
FROM    MyTable mt INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name,
                    MAX(date) date
            FROM    MyTable
            GROUP BY    Name
        ) lastDate  ON  mt.Name = lastDate.Name
                    AND mt.date = lastDate.date
```